# Update value in a dictionnary with React Hooks/ JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, react-hooks, jsx

I have a dictionnary in which I want to re-format some data because when I receive them from my database, they are not formatted correctly. To do that, I store them in a dictionnary like so when the page is opened:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
db.collection('users').doc(auth.currentUser.uid).get().then((response)=> {setData(response.data().appointments)})
```

and then I try to call a function to update the startDate and endDate keys' value automatically everytime the page is opened:

```
// This function re-formats and will be used in the next one
    function toDateTime(secs){
      var t = new Date(1970, 0, 1); // Epoch
      t.setSeconds(secs);
      //console.log(t)
      return t
    }

    // This function has to update the value
    function pwease(datis){
      var secondo = datis['startDate']['seconds']
      var secondu = datis['endDate']['seconds']
      var upDatis = {
        ...datis,
        endDate : toDateTime(secondu),
        startDate: toDateTime(secondo)
      }
      setData([...data, upDatis])
      return upDatis;
      
    }
    
    useEffect(()=> data.forEach((elt)=>{pwease(elt); console.log('Heu')}), [])
```

note: elements of my 'data' object look like that:

```
{allDay: false,
endDate: nt {seconds: 1669204800, nanoseconds: 0},
id: 0,
startDate: nt {seconds: 1669203000, nanoseconds: 0},
title: "cjlk"}
```

But I don't know why it doesn't work and the 'Heu' doesn't get printed. Please help cause I've been stuck for days on that. Thanks!

Comment: Do you get some error message (in the developer tools console, F12)? I mean, if "Heu" is not printed that means your code is not executed

Comment: It's a bit confusing to understand your error/goal. Anyways, inside your `useEffect` hook you are looping over `data` state which has initial value of empty array `[]` so of course nothing is happening. And if you cause any `data` changes later on in your code, you also **can't** pass `data` as dependency since that will cause *infinite re-renders* any time `data` updates -> your useEffect is calling `pwease` but you are updating `data` inside your `pwease` function which causes `data` changes which causes useEffect to call `pwease` ... and so on. You may want to create another `updatedState`.

Comment: Now, any idea of how I could go through `data` and do the changes for each element?

Comment: And there is no error in the console